# Finding shared segments between two shapes (line) using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have two line shapefiles. I want to find between them, where are located all shared segments and extract the new selection shapefile.

I am using QGIS. I know that in ArcGIS, there are a tool, named "share line segment with".

Is there some tool like this in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

go to Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Intersect; select the two shapefiles you want to analyse and set a name and location for the result shapefile.

Comment: Hello. I have already done it but the result shapefile is empty even if i invert the order of the input vector layer and intersect layer in the intersection box. Now i am trying to use SAGA (line-polygon intersection) where one of the layer is a line and the other is a polygon. But it gives me an error: "Saga folder is not configured". I have tryed to configure it but no results. How can I resove it? Thank you

Comment: Regarding QGIS Intersection: Make sure that both of your layers have the same CRS. To reproject them save them in the same CRS and load them again. For SAGA: You need to download it (google saga-gis), extract it into a folder and then open the sextante options (Analysis menu-> sextante options) and point sextante directly to the extracted folder (doubleclick provider saga dir)