# QGIS equivalent of ArcMap spatial join - share a line segment with

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I have two polylines shapefiles that I wish to join together spatially.
One is a road network and the other consists of bus routes which I have calculated the frequency over a certain period of time. I then wish to change the size of road segments based on this frequency.

I have found a successful way to do it in ArcMap, using the "SHARE_A_LINE_SEGMENT_WITH" option in the Spatial Join tool. Afterwards, I dissolve the joined shapefile based on the road_id column and sum the frequency column, also in ArcMap.

As shown [in this great visual example](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-by-location-graphical-examples.htm), *share a line segment with* is quite different from *intersect*, *contains*, *within* or other methods offered in QGIS.

Is there some way to perform this type of spatial join in QGIS, whether with a tool, plugin, or spatial SQL query?

My python knowledge is really poor.

[How to find share segments between two shapes (line) using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53545/how-to-find-share-segments-between-two-shapes-line-using-qgis) seems to be the same question as mine, however I can't comment to ask if there is any update.

Also, I found [Understanding Join Attributes by Location in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/understanding-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis) for QGIS, where no operation seems to be what I want exactly.

This is the road network:

[image: road shapefile]

With bus routes on top:

[image: bus and road shapefiles]

When I do a simple intersect, i'm left with a bunch of routes (in red) that shouldn't be there (circled in blue). I' guessing because of the segment ends.

[image: intersect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `dissolve` the road network
2. extract the vertices as points
3. split the road network with those points. This can be done with the SAGA tool `split lines at points` (in the Processing Toolbox under *vector line tools*).
4. do a spatial join (using the tool `join attributes by location`) with the "equals" geometry predicate

For a large or complicated road network the spatial join with the extracted nodes may take a while (in this case around 15-20 minutes). It should be faster to first `intersect` the road network, then run the above process on the intersected network.